# Zend framework - Auth: additional validation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I want to check the user table for status=1 as extra validation. My getAuthAdapter() method looks like this:

```
private function getAuthAdapter (){
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter());
    $authAdapter->setTableName('vi_users')
                ->setIdentityColumn('email')
                ->setCredentialColumn('password');
    return $authAdapter;
}
```

How would I alter this to include the extra validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
    $db,
    'users',
    'username',
    'password',
    'MD5(?) AND status = 1'
);
```

where $db would be Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()

Taken from http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.dbtable.html

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this problem myself, and I'm not sure it is possible to check another column at the sametime.  So I do it straight aftwerwards, with something like this:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

....

if (process($form->getValues())) {
    // login credentials are correct, so we now need to check if their account is activated
    if ($auth->getIdentity()->active != 1) {
        // if not, log them out and tell them to activate
        Zend_Auth::getInstance()->clearIdentity();
        $output .= "Your account has not yet been activated, please check your email (including spam bin) for the activation link.";
    } else {
        // if they're active then login is successful
        $output .= "You are now logged in";
    }
} else {
   // username/password wrong
   $output .= "Credentials invalid";
}
```

**Update:** Given Orlando's answer, it looks like what you've asked for originally is possible.  You could use my solution though if you would like to distinguish between `status` value being 'wrong' and user/pass being wrong.

Comment: I did it this way too, and yes, it's sometimes useful to know if the login succeed anyway.